In js why does null return object oncalling typeOf
const score = null;

console.log(typeof score);

shouldn't it return null?? why does it return object.
Null is supposedly empty, so while returning shouldn't it return null? but the code above returns object. I am still beginner in js.

In JS, null expresses a lack of identification, indicating that a variable points to no object. That is why, typeof null is not null, its an object.
W3School: In JavaScript null is "nothing". It is supposed to be something that doesn't exist.Unfortunately, in JavaScript, the data type of null is an object.
Reference link: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_typeof.asp#:~:text=Try%20it%20Yourself%20%C2%BB-,Null,of%20null%20is%20an%20object.
